# Realm Swift and Swift server

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform, perfect

Is it possible to use RealmSwift on a server running Swift (eg Perfect, Vapor, Kitura etc.) and use it to store data?

(I was thinking to try it as an alternative to another solution, eg node.js+express+mongoDB.)

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible ?
There are also MongoDB drivers for Swift. So you can use Swift + Mongo

Comment: I am interested in the reactive features of Realm, and I already use it in my apps so I am already familiar with it.

Comment: I would note that in your question. The fact, that you are interested in the reactive aspect. Meaning: using it with RxSwift, etc.

Comment: I most probably will use RxSwift but Realm already has reactive features by itself (notifications, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm Swift is only available on Darwin platforms. Eventual Linux support is possible, but would require considerable changes to both Swift and Realm. This is being tracked in https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3263